# How do you generate the shapes at the bottom of the image? Is is done with a filter or manually?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector

[image]

I'm sorry if this is a noob question. I use photoshop a lot, but not illustrator. Do you draw these manually? or is there a filter for this? Do you use a separate software like 3d studio max or mathematica?

Comment: They are drawn manually.

Answer (score 5):

Photoshop is terrible at outputting vector art, so it was likely not used for this. Usually if something is advertised as "vector" (as is the image), then it is likely created in a vector program. Illustrator is probably the most popular, but it could be any vector program.

3D Studio Max would be overkill for this. It's not all that difficult to create a pattern of random triangles in Illustrator:

[image: Illustrator Screenshot: some triangles]

Then add some random color:

[image: Illustrator Screenshot: some colored triangles]

Then add some uniform dots:

[image: Illustrator Screenshot: some colored triangles with transparent white dots]

Comment: I'll add that it's very easy to tile a plane with triangles. All that's left to do is drag-select all the anchor points that share a common 'vertex' and move them around slightly.

Comment: Good point @Alex!

Comment: THANKS! I figured out a different way of doing it.
Find colorful image >> Mosaic >> Crystalize
But it didn't turn out as triangular as I wanted. Sorry, I confused this with another question I wanted to ask but couldn't figure out how to phrase. I'm also interested in making an automated way to make polygons / polyhedra line art, like with difference clouds and actions. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you could also use some of the excellent Scriptographer plugins to easily create the shapes:

http://scriptographer.org/scripts/raster-scripts/hexagonal-grid-generator/

http://scriptographer.org/scripts/general-scripts/grid-generator/

(although they don't work if you are using Illustrator CS6 or newer)